# mySql match any character from the string

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to be able to match any of the given characters to the WHERE clause.

For example if I have entry in the table with following description field

**"Blue T-shirt XL with a lion on the back"**

After:

```
SELECT* FROM products WHERE name LIKE 'tshirt'
```

...nothing is returned

I can perhaps explode string in php and use a wildcard % after every letter, but that sound like a lot of operations for a small task.

Does anyone have a better approach to this please?

Many thanks

Comment: You currently have 4 people suggesting wildcards after you said you wanted a better approach... there _might_ be ways to modify your database (e.g. adding a keywords column and matching against that) to get what you ultimately want; if you clarify what  you want, you might get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
$filter = implode('%',str_split($filter));
$filter = '%'.$filter.'%';
```

and then executing sql:

> select * from products where name like $filter

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `%` which is a [wildcard](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) in like..

```
SELECT* FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%shirt%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%`:

```
SELECT* FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%tshirt%'
```

`%` is a substitute for zero or more characters.

Since the letters may change, you should convert it to lower or upper :

**Complete and perfect query:**

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%tshirt%' 
   OR lower(name) LIKE '%t_shirt%'
```

`_` is a substitute for a single character.

See more examples in [**wildcards**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%tshirt%';
```

This matches anything that contains the string 'tshirt'. % is the wildcard character.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need wildcards:

```
where name like '%tshirt%'
```

However, that still won't totally help, because of the hyphen.  You can also use `lower()` to ensure that case does not matter.  Perhaps this is more what you want:

```
where replace(lower(name), '-', '') like '%tshirt%'
```

or perhaps:

```
where lower(name) like '%t%shirt%'
```